# Using response data from Python in Typescript

Tags: python, typescript

I'm using [instagrapi](https://github.com/adw0rd/instagrapi) which revolves around python:

```py
from instagrapi import Client;

app = Client()
app.login('username', 'password')

medias = app.user_medias('user_id')
print(medias)
```

Now, the python app returns an `application/json` response, which I'd like to use in my typescript app.

The main question is: **How do I link python to a typescript app?**

I'd like to receive my response from python which I want to use in the typescript app. I'm looking for ideas / methods to do so.

> I wanted to use sqlite as a medium to transfer data, but as the app would be used by at least 100 users, sqlite wouldn't be a consistent way to get the job done

Comment: Is that Typescript app for node.js or a browser? Why even use Python at all? A quick search shows there are API implementations for node.js (no idea how good they are)

Comment: typescript for node.js, oh and I tried other API implementations and they don't seem to work as good as `instagrapi`... moreover the rest version of it returns a `403` error

Comment: Just have a python script that calls the API and dumps the result to STDOUT, probably as JSON which you can then parse back into data on the TS side.